# Cannot remove fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

What I'm trying to do here is to add a fragment on incoming "show" broadcast (this works fine) and then remove it on incoming "hide" broadcast - this doesn't work, fragment is not hidden (but the broadcast is sent). Both `fragmentTransaction.add()` and `fragmentTransaction.remove()` are called but only fragmentTransaction.add() works. After calling `fragmentTransaction.remove()` the fragment is still present.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.v("receiver", "Got message");

  if(intent.getStringExtra("message").equals("show")) {

      Log.v("fragment", "I'm trying show!");

      fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      Remote fragment2 = new Remote();
      fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2, "RecordingRemote");
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
      fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();


        } else if (intent.getStringExtra("message").equals("hide")) {

      Log.v("fragment", "I'm trying to hide!");

      fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("RecordingRemote");
      fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
      fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

  }

    }
};
```

Registration:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("Recording"));

// ...

}
```

Comment: Did you register the receiver for the correct intentFilter? Did you register it prior to the event being broadcast? Raise the logging level to something like warn just for testing or use a debugger. Add the registration code to the problem to help us understand what we are trying to do.

Comment: And the sender? Does this happen after the registration?

Comment: Yes, receiver is registered. I've just changed `Log.v()` to `  System.out.println` and now I know that both `fragmentTransaction.add()` and `fragmentTransaction.remove()` are called but only `fragmentTransaction.add()` works.

Comment: you have to call `commit()` when removing :) not just `executePendingTransactions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a Commit in the whole transaction.

```
    fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    fragmentTransaction.commit(); // THIS ONE YOU DON'T HAVE
```

Comment: You can commit a FragmentTransaction, not a FragmentManager.